# How to do a "LIVE CHART" in c# using Live charts winforms

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, livecharts

I found many samples of codes for using LiveCharts in C# but I can't understand how it works. I already downloaded the package in my Visual Studio. I am working on a project that is connected to arduino that has 2 different gas sensors, one is for gaseous compounds, and the other is for particulates, then arduino will send the data to my c# application and records it to a mysql database. My only problem is on how I could graph this using LiveCharts. I am planning to use a line graph with two lines for the two data. Please help.

I found out that the code that I need is the constant changes live charts. I tried it but it says:
'Timer' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Windows.Forms.Timer' and 'System.Threading.Timer'

Comment: please try to provide an example, with a specific problem. You can also read here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve